# Reading log file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a log file with following content.
I like to read `Iteration value` and `detection_eval` value

```
I0704 18:10:31.097334  2421 solver.cpp:433] Iteration 200, Testing net (#0)
I0704 18:10:31.149454  2421 net.cpp:693] Ignoring source layer mbox_loss
I0704 18:10:40.241916  2421 solver.cpp:546]     Test net output #0: detection_eval = 0.00273318
```

I did

```
accuracy_pattern = r"Iteration (?P<iter_num>\d+), Testing net \(#0\)\n.* detection_eval = (?P<accuracy>[+-]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?)"
```

But nothing is read, what is the issue?

EDIT:
Then I read accuracy_pattern to array as

```
for r in re.findall(accuracy_pattern, log):
        iteration = int(r[0])
        accuracy = float(r[1]) * 100
```

log has all file content and read as follow

```
with open(log_file, 'r') as log_file2:
        log = log_file2.read()
```

Comment: But what did you do with `accuracy_pattern`? It's just a string. Strings do not read files.

Comment: @DyZ I have EDIT. Thanks

Comment: And what's a `log`? How is it initialized?

Comment: @DyZ I have updated.

Comment: Is `detection_eval = ...` always at the end of the line?

Comment: yes it is always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your data, the following regex should work:

```
pattern = "Iteration\s+(\d+)|detection_eval\s+=\s+(.+$)"
for it,de in re.findall(pattern, log, flags=re.M):
    if it: 
        print('Iteration', int(it))
    if de:
        print('detection_eval', float(de))
#Iteration 200
#detection_eval 0.00273318
```

However, reading the whole log file at once is usually a bad idea. Consider reading one line at a time:

```
with open(log_file, 'r') as log_file2:
    for line in log_file2:
        for it,de in re.findall(pattern, log):
            if it: 
                print('Iteration', int(it))
            if de:
                print('detection_eval', float(de))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.search`

**Demo:**

```
import re

with open(log_file, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        iteration = re.search("Iteration (\d+)", line)
        if iteration:
            print iteration.group()

        detection_eval = re.search("detection_eval = (\d.*)", line)
        if detection_eval:
            print detection_eval.group()
```

**Output:**

```
Iteration 200
detection_eval = 0.00273318
```

Or using `re.findall`

```
iteration = re.findall(r"Iteration (\d+)", log )
detection_eval = re.findall(r"detection_eval = (\d.*)", log )
```